# Three ADSLs on a single router

Tags: load-balancing

I know that my question sounds impossible, but I would go deeper into it.

I have three Internet connections:

1. ADSL from Provider 1;
2. ADSL from Provider 2;
3. LTE from Provider 3 (USB WiFi Box).

I need to direct all three connections into a router and serve my hosts with a single WiFi connection. They only see a line called `Office_WiFi`, but they hiddenly connect alternately to the three Internet connection (so three different public IPs).

My need is to balance the load of the line and manage band for every hosts. Ex: `Host 1` needs to upload a large file, my network automatically gives him priority and sets him on `ADSL from provider 1` instead of `LTE from Provider 3 (USB WiFi Box)`.

Is there a way to do this?

Someone told me to start using `pfSense`. Could `pfSense` help me in this challenge?

Thank you all!

Ps: the problem is having three WANs and a single LAN.

Answer (score 1):

You could use MikroTik RouterOS. http://www.mikrotik.com

It allows you to setup all 3 internet gateways any way you want and apply any rules you need to load balance the connections.

It may have a steep learning curve though depending on your knowledge on networking since you configure everything manually extactly to your needs. There are no wizards.
It has a pretty usable UI though which make everything much easier.

On MikroTik's wiki there are numerous tutorials on load balancing, etc.

The company that develops RouterOS also produces and various hardware routers based on MikroTik RouterOS called 'Routerboard'. http://www.routerboard.com
So you also have the option to get a single routerboard and put all your internet connections on it. Or you could use an old PC to make it a router.

If you need a free/opensource solution I guess pfsense might do the job, but I haven't used it extensively my self so I don't know the options it gives you regarding load balancing.